# My iTextSharp5 password protection doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, itext

My goal is to add password protection to a copy of an arbitrary non-password protected PDF using iTextSharp5.  I tried the code below, which I found in several places on the Internet.  However, I can still open the supposedly protected file without a password using Adobe Acrobat.  If instead use Adobe Acrobat itself to password protect the file rather than iTextSharp, the resulting file does then require a password to open.  What am I doing wrong?

```
using (Stream input = new FileStream(@"Original.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
   using (Stream output = new FileStream(@"New.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
   {
      PdfReader PDFreader = new PdfReader(input);
      PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(PDFreader, output, true, null, "password", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As usual it was lack of knowledge and operator error.  I only had a password set for the "owner".  The "user" password was null.  Once I set the "user" password it started working correctly.